# need to count number of specific transitions in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I am programming a sampler in R, which basically is a big for loop, and for every Iterations I have to count the number of transitions in a vector. I have a vector called k, which contains zeros and ones, with 1000 entries in the vector.

I have used the following, horribly slow, code:

```
#we determine the number of transitions n00,n01,n10,n11
  n00=n01=n10=n11=0 #reset number of transitions between states from last time
  for(j in 1:(1000-1)){
    if(k[j+1]==1 && k[j]==0) {n01<-n01+1}
    else { if(k[j+1]==1 && k[j]==1) {n11<-n11+1}
           else { if(k[j+1]==0 && k[j]==1) {n10<-n10+1}
                  else{n00<-n00+1}
           }

    }
  }
```

So for every time the loop goes, the variables n00,n01,n10,n11 counts the transitions in the vector. For example, n00 counts number of times a 0 is followed by another 0. And so on...

This is very slow, and I am very new to R, so I am kind of desperate here. I do not understand how to use grep, if that even is possible.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
x <- sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE)
> table(paste0(head(x,-1),tail(x,-1)))

00 01 10 11 
 4  3  4  8
```

The `head` and `tail` return portions of the vector `x`: all but the last element, and then all but the first element. This means that the corresponding elements are the consecutive pairs from `x`.

Then `paste0` just converts each one to a character vector and pastes the first elements, the second element, etc. The result is a character vector with elements like "00", "01", etc. Then `table` just counts up how many of each there are.

You can assign the result to a new variable like so:

```
T <- table(paste0(head(x,-1),tail(x,-1)))
```

Experiment yourself with each piece of the code to see how it works. Run just `head(x,-1)`, etc. to see what each piece does.

To address the comment below, to ensure that all types appear with counts when you run `table`, convert it to a factor first:

```
x1 <- factor(paste0(head(x,-1),tail(x,-1)),levels = c('00','01','10','11'))
table(x1)
```

Comment: great answer!  use the following if paste0 fails: table(paste(head(x,-1),tail(x,-1),sep=""))

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! Although I have no idea how the code works. That is, I do not understand the paste0 mixed with the head and tail functions. Anyway, I am super greatful! Thank you so much!

is it any way I can get out the data from the table?
For example:
T<-table(paste0(head(x,-1),tail(x,-1))) and afterward write T$00 or something?

I am sorry for my total lack of brains, but I am as I said totally new to this.

Comment: @ErosRam If my answer solved your problem, feel free to click the little check mark next to it so that this question is marked as solved. I'll add some explanation to my answer.

Comment: Yes I am sorry :D My first questions and answer here, so I forgot. Thank you, again! This is genius!

Comment: Btw, just a small follow-up. Since my vector k is changing all the time, sometimes it is all zeros. Then the table gives me the values NA when it more conveniently should give me zero. Is there any way to bypass this?

What I mean is: when all my 1000 values are zeros, which is the case for the first time i run my sampler, what I get is:
> cp<-table(paste0(head(k,-1),tail(k,-1)))
> cp

 00 
1000

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
# my sample: [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0

rl <- rle(x)

zero_to_zero <- sum(rl$len[rl$val == 0 & rl$len > 1] - 1)
one_to_one <- sum(rl$len[rl$val == 1 & rl$len > 1] - 1)

zero_to_one <- sum(diff(rl$val) == -1)
one_to_zero <- sum(diff(rl$val) == 1)

x
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
zero_to_zero
# [1] 4

one_to_one
# [1] 1

zero_to_one
# [1] 2

one_to_zero
# [1] 2
```

@joran's answer is faaaar cleaner though...Still, I thought I just as well could finish the stroll I started down (the dirty) trail, and share the result.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't care about distinguishing the n00 and n11 cases, then this becomes much simpler:

```
x <- sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE)
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

table(diff(x))      
# -1  0  1 
#  4 11  4
```

Since the question says that you're primarily interested in the transitions, this may be acceptable, otherwise one of the other answers would be preferable.